# GMP mpz_pow_ui with very large exponent

Tags: c++, gmp, exponent

i have very large exponent, where exponent

```
e = 26959946667150639794667015087019630673637144422540572481103610249951
```

(225 bits)

But, according to mpz_pow_ui template as follows:

```
void mpz_pow_ui (mpz_t ROP, mpz_t BASE, unsigned long int EXP)
```

I think e does not fit to that function, is there another way to calculate large exponent using GMP C++?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't. If the base value being exponentiated is anything other than `-1`, `0`, or `1`, you'll blow main memory (you'll exceed the available virtual address space entirely). If the goal is to do modular exponentiation (where the result *can* fit in memory because it's reduced mod some number that fits in RAM), you want [`mpz_powm`](https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Exponentiation.html#Integer-Exponentiation) (or `mpz_powm_sec` if you're writing "real" crypto code; the `_sec` variant defends against timing attacks for key recovery).

The reason GMP only accepts an unsigned integer for that function is because arbitrary precision exponents only lead to tears in this case.

Comment: Wow.. thank you so much @ShadowRanger.. I don't know if there is exist function like mpz_powm, I need to modulus the value after that..

Comment: @stranger: I figured. No one uses an exponent that large for any other purpose. :-)